# Netbeans java, open a cmd-window on build

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, cmd

I wish to be able to do the following under Windows (Windows 7):

1. Press Build on a Netbeans Project
2. Build the project
3. Have it open and execute the generated jar in a cmd-window

Why do I want this? To be sure that it works, and to be able to send a Control-C to the terminal/console.

I think it could be achieved via Ant, but please help me on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by extending NetBeans' build script. To do that, do the following:

1. Open the "Files" window (Window -> Files)
2. Open the `nbbuild.xml` file in the directory with the name of your project.
3. Add the following code to it:

   ```
   <target name="-post-jar">
     <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="${dist.dir}">
       <arg value="/k"/>
       <arg value='start "MyApp" java -jar ${dist.jar}'/>
     </exec>
   </target>
   ```

Now when you build your project the `-post-jar` target will be called once NetBeans is finished with the build. This will start a commandline window to run your project. As an alternative you could also override the `run` target. An example on how to do that is inside the `nbbuild.xml` file.

Note that you have to use the `start` command, otherwise the console window won't be visible (at least I don't know of any other way).

This also assumes that you have a self-executable jar file that can be started using `java -jar ...`. If that is not the case you will need to assemble the full classpath to be passed to the `java` command.

Some more information about customizing NetBeans' build process can be found in the online help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40938_01/doc.74/e40142/create_japps.htm#CHDDAHEB

Having said all that: to verify that your application works correctly, it would be a ***much*** better choice to write proper unit tests.

Comment: Just one quick comment: I cannot check shutdown hooks or properly exit my program with unit tests or even in Netbeans :(